# Memory warning while creating mp4 video from image array

Tags: ios

I am trying to create a video file the image files. I am setting the name of image files in a NSArray. When the number of image files is large(more than 80 or 100), I am getting memory warning and sometimes app crashes. This is my code:

```
   -(void)writeImageAsMovie:(NSArray *)images toPath:(NSString*)path size:(CGSize)size duration:(int)duration
{

    NSError *error = nil;

    videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:
                   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                               error:&error];


    NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

    NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                                   nil];
    AVAssetWriterInput* writerInput = [AVAssetWriterInput
                                       assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                       outputSettings:videoSettings] ;




    AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
                                                     assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput
                                                     sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];


    NSParameterAssert(writerInput);
    NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:writerInput]);
    [videoWriter addInput:writerInput];


    //Start a session:
    [videoWriter startWriting];
    [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1000)];

    CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;

    //convert uiimage to CGImage.

    //Write samples:
    for (int i=0; i<images.count ; i++) {

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[images objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"image"]]];
        int time = [[[images objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"time"] intValue];
        buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:image.CGImage];
        while(! adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData );
        [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:CMTimeMake(time,1000)];
        image=nil;
    }

    while(!adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData);


    //Finish the session:
    [writerInput markAsFinished];

    [videoWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^(){
        NSLog (@"finished writing %d",images.count);
    }];

    NSLog(@"%d",[videoWriter status]);
    while([videoWriter status] != AVAssetWriterStatusFailed && [videoWriter status] != AVAssetWriterStatusCompleted) {
        NSLog(@"Status: %d", [videoWriter status]);
        sleep(1);
    }
    NSLog(@"%d",[videoWriter status]);
    NSString *tmpdir = NSTemporaryDirectory();
    NSString *mydir = [tmpdir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"vidimages"];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:mydir error:nil];

    }




    - (CVPixelBufferRef) pixelBufferFromCGImage: (CGImageRef) image
    {
        CGFloat screenWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;

        NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                                 nil];
        CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;

        CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, screenWidth,
                                              screenWidth, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) options,
                                              &pxbuffer);
        NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != NULL);

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
        void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);

        NSParameterAssert(pxdata != NULL);

        CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGContextRef context1 = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, screenWidth,
                                                      screenWidth, 8, 4*screenWidth, rgbColorSpace,
                                                      kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);
        NSParameterAssert(context1);
        CGContextConcatCTM(context1, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0));
        CGContextDrawImage(context1, CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth,
                                                screenWidth), image);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
        CGContextRelease(context1);

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);

        return pxbuffer;
    }
```

Comment: You use memory as much as available. This is why you were warned and/or system crashed. This is not the problem of your code, but the problem of system. Virtual memory may help sometimes, and may cause the system more unstable (more often crash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like here that a slab of autoreleased UIImage and NSData objects are being allocated:

```
for (int i=0; i<images.count ; i++) {

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[images objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"image"]]];
    int time = [[[images objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"time"] intValue];
    buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:image.CGImage];
    while(! adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData );
    [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:CMTimeMake(time,1000)];
    image=nil;
}
```

To get the autoreleased objects released each pass through the loop, and stop the memory usage ramping up rapidly, add an autorelease pool, i.e:

```
for (int i=0; i<images.count ; i++) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[images objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"image"]]];
        int time = [[[images objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"time"] intValue];
        buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:image.CGImage];
        while(! adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData );
        [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:CMTimeMake(time,1000)];
        image=nil;
    }
}
```

Look in the Apple doco for autorelease pools if you're unfamiliar- yes they're still relevant with ARC.